# How to connect to VPN using commands in Linux (Fedora 16)

Tags: linux, vpn

Usually, I use the network connections icon on the top bar to connect to VPN.

[image: VPN Connection]

The connection is configured properly and it connects well. Configuration screen shot is given below.

[image]

As you can see I have selected the 'Connect automatically' option. But this option doesn't help in connecting to VPN automatically upon login.

This is my university VPN and it uses 'Point-to-Point encryption (MPPE)' for authentication
[image]

I need to connect to the VPN using command line, so that I can write a script and run it at start up, so the connection is automatically established every time I login. This will also help in connecting to VPN when I login from 'init 3' mode. I depend on this VPN connection for my internet access. Please help me with the required commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NetworkManager [command line interface](https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nmcli.html).